# Wind Load on conical structure

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, fluid, wind

Is there a way to calculate the wind load acting on this conical cylinder?
The wind pressure blowing through the hollow conical cylinder is at 30 bar. The conical cylinder is tilted at 10 degree downwards.

[image: Wind pressure of 30 bar blowing into the conical cylinder]

What I did was to get the surface area where the wind is touching which is 9.169m^2.

[image: Surface Area]

I put the number into the Wind Load Calculator sites.
https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wind-load

Surface Area: 9.169m^2
Surface Angle: 6.552 degree
Dynamic Pressure: 30 bar

And the site calculate for me 3138.7 kN wind load.

But I know it is not right as the calculation is only meant for flat surface.

Comment: So did you calculate the effective surface area? as the surface is at an angle to the assumed flat surface?

Comment: I like the effort and way of thinking but your best chance is doing some CFD.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, which is not correct as the curve would effect the flow and the overall force.

Comment: @SamiSafarini I had tried Simscale but the free version was not able to calculate 30 bar of wind pressure and I am still trying to understand how to use it. I do not have aerospace or building manufacturer background and I was wondering if there is away to calculate manually.

Comment: @Matt Can you share the model with us?

Comment: @SamiSafarini I do not know how to share the model here.

Comment: @Matt Have you considered a google drive link?

Comment: @SamiSafarini Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gCNE9lqO9LhTwbSXxo3-nEwyVwA2gHR2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Matt do you have a better quality one?

Comment: @Matt Does the 30bar equate to 0.5*rho*V^2 when you say dynamic pressure? it seems like alot what is the application?

Comment: @SamiSafarini Better quality: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpahBJQKyNZN8SDmc9uZ5jLX3LSme9lD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SamiSafarini Yes it seems alot and I do not know what it is for as I am only given 30 bar to calculate.

Comment: @Matt, is this a homework exercise?

Comment: @SamiSafarini It is from my work.

Comment: Hi @Matt are you able to get the model to be square with some axis, preferably with the x-axis being the stream direction and z axis being the rotation axis? Better quality would also be good.

Comment: @SamiSafarini How about this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R7ax4JFBI6zs-X5UNHjyQlyYcvgbnEui/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I managed to get to unfortunately, I wouldn't use these numbers without a validation test but I ran some simulations between 0 and 440 ms^-1 at the inlet to generate a rule which I extrapolated to 2200ms^-1 .
If you assume you have an inlet velocity of 2200ms^-1 then you are looking at a drag in the order of 780KN +- 10KN.

I will edit this answer if I can get a better result.
[image: Plot of Drag vs Inlet Velocity]

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Seems like your simulation results is significantly lower value than the flat surface calculation. The recent model I gave was at 0 degree rotation, may I know if your simulation model at 0 degree or 10 degree rotation?

Comment: I tilted it by 10 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across Ansys and tried to study it.
I tilted the cylinder at 10 degrees and put 30 bar for the inlet. I tried to play around with the result and I found "forces pressure". I selected the internal surface of the cylinder for all the X,Y,Z "forces pressure". I'm not sure if that is the right force, correct me if I wrong. What I get was -1343291.1N.

[image]

I select the forces under the results tab.

[image]

I select the cylinder internal surface and get the combine forces of the X,Y,Z directions by changing 0 to 1 on the direction vector.

[image]

I print the results and get the total forces of -1343291.1N.
I'm not sure but am I correct to say that this is the wind load?